# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':flypandroid:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

getting this error after upgrading to Studio 2.1 and building against API 23:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':flypandroid:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/NonNull.class

I have tried:

Build->Clean

and

gradelw clean

```
 configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.annotation'
}
```

nothing has worked.

looking at all the jars in libs, only the android-support-v13.jar has the NonNull class.

here is my dependencies list:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':newQuickAction')
compile project(':emojicon')
compile project(':newQuickAction')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/aternity_sdk-7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar')
androidTestCompile files('libs/crittercism_v4_5_4_sdkonly.jar')
compile files('libs/emojitextview.jar')
compile files('libs/flypsi-0.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.6.jar')
compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
compile files('libs/prettytime.jar')
compile files('libs/Pubnub-Android-3.7.4.jar')
compile files('libs/PubnubCrypto.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
compile files('libs/flyp-domain-1.12.0.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/flyp-util-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ok, after struggling with this for awhile, I was able to find a solution specific to my situation (not general).

the problem was with this jar: libs/android-support-v13.jar and specifically, the class android.support.annotation.NonNull (note that the jar contains the annotation package as well as v4 and v13 packages). It seems like the gradle process was having issues with the annotation package and I wanted to separate this dependency out.

so, I removed android-support-v13.jar from the libs dir and instead used the library dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
```

then, to include the v4 support I tried to include the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

however, this DID NOT WORK! the code would not build due to missing classes, packages etc. that should have been found.

instead, I manually copied the android-support-v4.jar into the libs dir over from the android sdk and specified:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

and it worked. my final dependencies list looks like this:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':newQuickAction')
compile project(':emojicon')
compile project(':newQuickAction')
//compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/aternity_sdk-7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.5.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar')
androidTestCompile files('libs/crittercism_v4_5_4_sdkonly.jar')
compile files('libs/emojitextview.jar')
compile files('libs/flypsi-0.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.6.jar')
compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
compile files('libs/prettytime.jar')
compile files('libs/Pubnub-Android-3.7.4.jar')
compile files('libs/PubnubCrypto.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
compile files('libs/flyp-domain-1.12.0.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1'
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
compile files('libs/facebook.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

}